# How to make Spring WebClient return Specific Exception with correct structure from A microservice in the second microservice after calling endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, webclient

I have two microservices A and B. I am making a call from B to A microservice endpoint using Spring WebClient. For example, If I make the direct call to A microservice endpoint with incorrect parameters I get a specific Exception `ConstraintViolationException` and the structure is provided as described in my `@ControllerAdvice` class. But if I use Spring WebClient to call I get `WebClientRequestException.BadRequest`.

How can I just pass the original Exception `ConstraintViolationException` from microservice A to B when using the WebClient instead of just receiving `WebClientRequestException.BadRequest` ?